# Create a pandas column based on existing columns: conditional min of a column grouped by another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame similar to this:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2], 'b':[-1,3,2,-1,4,9,6,6]})
df
```

I want to add a third column which is grouped by col 'a' min of column 'b' where col 'b' != -1.
if 'b' = -1 I want -1 to be replaced in col 'min'.
the result should look like this:

```
'a'  'b'  'min'
 1   -1     -1
 2    3      3
 1    2      2
 2   -1     -1
 1    4      2
 2    9      3
 1    6      2
 2    6      3
```

What is the best and most efficient way of doing this using pandas?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter column by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `min` and last add [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) for set unmatched values:

```
df['min'] = (df.loc[df['b'] != -1, 'b']
               .groupby(df['a'])
               .transform('min')
               .reindex(df.index, fill_value=-1))
print (df)
   a  b  min
0  1 -1   -1
1  2  3    3
2  1  2    2
3  2 -1   -1
4  1  4    2
5  2  9    3
6  1  6    2
7  2  6    3
```